# Is there a way to make Borders in ItemsControl clickable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a table view like this:

[image: table view]

These cells are different from each other. I want those cells to be clickable. But I couldn't figure out how to do it. On Android, there is a listener called
setOnItemClickListener but I don't know the equivalent on WPF. I know SelectedItem can be used for ListView but I need this exact view. I can't customize ListView.

Here is the code that I created for this table view:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ListViewTableBorder" ItemsSource="{Binding TableName}" Selector.Selected="ListViewTableBorder_Selected">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource sales_border}" MouseLeftButtonUp="Border_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <TextBlock Name="tablename" Text="{Binding tablename}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Here is the sales_border styles:

```
  <Style x:Key="sales_border" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a7d38"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00d052"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here is the table data that I've used to create those cells.

```
  public hall_layout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var tablename = GetTableNames();
        if (tablename.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewTableBorder.ItemsSource = tablename;
        }
    }

    private List<TableName> GetTableNames()
    {
        return new List<TableName>()
        {
            new TableName("Salon 1"),
            new TableName("Salon 2"),
            new TableName("Salon 3"),
            new TableName("Salon 4"),
            new TableName("Salon 5"),
            new TableName("Salon 6"),
            new TableName("Salon 7"),
            new TableName("Salon 8"),
            new TableName("Salon 9"),
            new TableName("Salon 10"),
            new TableName("Salon 11"),
            new TableName("Salon 12"),
            new TableName("Salon 13"),
            new TableName("Salon 14"),
            new TableName("Salon 15"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
            new TableName("Salon 16"),
        };
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `MouseLeftButtonUp="Border_MouseLeftButtonUp"` is close enough to click event

Comment: Just replace your `ItemsControl` with `ListBox` and use the `SelectionChanged` event

Comment: @Aakanksha Can I implement the exact same view using ListBox? I have couldn't done it before. If you post an answer then everything will be clear and I'll accept it

Comment: Yes it will be the same. You just need to replace ItemsControl with ListBox. Sure i'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemsControl` doesn't handle `SelectionChanged` and does not have `SelectedItem` property. Instead you can use `ListBox` with `ItemsPanel` as `WrapPanel`, then you will get the `SelectedItem` of `ListBox` and can handle `SelectionChanged`.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="ListViewTableBorder" ItemsSource="{Binding TableName}" SelectionChanged="ListViewTableBorder_Selected" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource sales_border}">
                            <TextBlock Name="tablename" Text="{Binding tablename}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```